# detect if configure/make was executed in a source directory

Tags: installation, bash, source-code

I have a script that installs a software. The script have answers prepared in advance in order to feed `checkinstall` with them. `checkinstall` prompts differently when the source has already been configured/make or not.
How can I tell if `configure` / `make` / `make install` was executed in the source directory?

Comment: Are you using plain make or autotools?

Comment: I'm executing `./configure`, `make` and `checkinstall`. But `checkinstall` is essentially `make install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand how your setup looks like, but when using autotools (like you seem to do) files are created from autotools template files like `configure.in` and `Makefile.am`.

The different steps then produce a number of files in the build directory you could check for.

- `./configure` creates e.g. `Makefile` and `config.status`
- `make` creates e.g files below `.deps` and `.libs`
- `make install` doesn't leave any traces in the build directory, but copies files to their install locations.

To check if `make install` was run you could supplement the default install rules, e.g. add to your `Makefile.am`

```
install-data-local:
        @touch .installed
```

and then check for `.installed`.

Since when using autotools there won't be no `Makefile` before running `./configure` you would have to handle this case differently.